# Realtime errors/warnings without file save in VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

VSCode can only report syntax errors/warnings after I save the file for Go. This behavior is different from other languages such as [dart](https://dartcode.org/). Can I have real time errors/warnings in Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Basically adding the following to user settings (settings.json):

```js
"go.liveErrors": {
  "enabled": true,
  "delay": 500
}
```

VSCode will then ask you to install the gotype-live tool. You can also install manually if you want with the following command:

```
go get -v github.com/tylerb/gotype-live
```